# how to detect if args is empty (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm doing the 8ball command for my bot (-8ball ) but when user types only 8ball command the bot crash, my code is this:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
   var command = "-8ball";
   if (message.content.startsWith(command)) {
     const args = message.content.slice(command.length).split(/ +/g);
     let respuesta = ["Si", "No", "Tal vez", "Obvio", "Yo digo que si", "Yo digo que no", "Probablemente"]
     var random = respuesta[Math.floor(Math.random() * respuesta.length)]
     const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .addField("Pregunta:", `${args.join(" ")}`)
        .addField("Respuesta:", `${random}`)
        .setColor("RANDOM")
     message.channel.send(embed)
   }
});
```

how i can detect if the args are empty?

Answer (score 0):

Since 0 is falsy:

```js
console.log(0 == false);
```

You could use `Array.prototype.length` (which will return 0 if there are no elements in the array)

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
  var command = "-8ball";
  if (message.content.startsWith(command)) {
    const args = message.content.slice(command.length).split(/ +/g);
    if (!args.length)
      return message.channel.send('You did not input a question');
    let respuesta = [
      "Si",
      "No",
      "Tal vez",
      "Obvio",
      "Yo digo que si",
      "Yo digo que no",
      "Probablemente",
    ];
    var random = respuesta[Math.floor(Math.random() * respuesta.length)];
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .addField("Pregunta:", `${args.join(" ")}`)
      .addField("Respuesta:", `${random}`)
      .setColor("RANDOM");
    message.channel.send(embed);
  }
});
```

Comment: This is not how falsiness works in JavaScript. Just because `[] == false`, does not mean `!![]` is `false` (it's not). A conditional `if ([]) ...` will run, because an empty array is truthy.

Answer (score 0):

this is true only if args is an array and is not empty

```
if (args instanceof Array && args.length)
```

use this if you need it the other way around

```
if (!(args instanceof Array && args.length))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for an empty array by simply checking its `length` property.

For example `!args.length` will return true if `args` has no elements, false if it has atleast 1 or more elements inside it

You can use this to check if args is empty

```
if (!args.length) {
   // Code To Execute If Args Is Empty
}
```

[More About Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

Answer (score 0):

You can just test for the first element of the array.

```
if(!args[0]) return;
```